# how create a coroutine inside a Controller method in order to call a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Goal: my microservice must consume another Rest endpoint and I am trying to follow [Coroutines (Async)](https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/09/30/java-11-http-client.html).

Here is how I coded in Service in order to consume another rest endpoint

Service

```
suspend fun getCoroutine(){

    val someData = getData()

    print(someData)
}

suspend fun getData(): String {

    
    val client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .authenticator(Authenticator.getDefault())
            .build();

    val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3000/employees"))
            .build();

    val response = client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return response.get().body() // suspend and return String not a Future
}
```

And I want "suspend fun getCoroutine()" method be called from my controller

```
package com.tolearn.endpoint

import com.tolearn.DemoGrpcKafkaReply
import com.tolearn.DemoGrpcKafkaRequest
import com.tolearn.DemoGrpcKafkaServiceGrpc
import com.tolearn.service.DemoService
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver
import java.util.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
class DemoEndpoint : DemoGrpcKafkaServiceGrpc.DemoGrpcKafkaServiceImplBase(){

    @Inject
    lateinit var demoService: DemoService

    override fun send(request: DemoGrpcKafkaRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<DemoGrpcKafkaReply>?) {

        demoService.getCoroutine()

    }
}
```

I am very new on Coroutine. I learned that a suspend function only can be evoked from anotehr suspend function or a Coroutine so, in my case I want to create a Coroutine. After googling I tried

```
override fun send(request: DemoGrpcKafkaRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<DemoGrpcKafkaReply>?) {

    val tryingCoroutine = runBlocking { demoService.getCoroutine() }
```

But runBlocking can't be resolved.

Also I tried based on [docs reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html) and also lauch can't be resolved

```
override fun send(request: DemoGrpcKafkaRequest?, responseObserver: StreamObserver<DemoGrpcKafkaReply>?) {
    
    launch( demoService.getCoroutine() ) { // not confined -- will work with main thread

    }
```

Here is the build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.13"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.tolearn"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}

micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.tolearn.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:'1.4.2")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.tolearn.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }


}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc")
            //srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/java")
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.33.1" }
        //grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            //grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN QUESTION: what I have to do to call a suspend function from the method of my Controller? A secondary question, am I doing some weird approach trying to call a suspend function from a Controller method? Am I wrong trying to take advantage of Coroutine in this case?

*** edit 1

```
val tryingCoroutine = runBlocking {
    coroutineScope { // Creates a coroutine scope
        launch {
            demoService.getCoroutine()
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }
    }
}
println(tryingCoroutine.isCompleted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `kotlinx-coroutines-core` dependency to resolve scopes(runBlocking/launch).

Here is the link to maven repo:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core

Scope documentation:
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html

Once you have scopes added to your project you should be able to run suspended functions within non-suspending block.Also, you making use `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to handle errors.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler

Technically, the controller should handoff any long-running operations to another thread and return the appropriate response. So you are doing anything weird.

Comment: Regard the dependency I had it in my gradle but unfortunatelly there was a typo before the version and I didn't get an error pointing to it (implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:'1.4.2"). I read the documentation and googled but I didn't learn exactlu how create a Scope. Kindly can you show a simple example? I am now able to call suspend function from my Controller but with this very simple approach: val tryingCoroutine = runBlocking { demoService.getCoroutine() }. Not sure if I am in right direction. Finally your last link pops 404

Comment: Based on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#scope-builder I created the Scope above (please see edit 1 above). Is it correct?Well it is working in IntelliJ debug but did I use properly Coroutine Scope in my context (calling a suspend function from a controller)? How should I properly handle exception here? Do I have to test if it is isCompleted?

Comment: This will help you to create a custom scope and handle the cancellation as well. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/